# Good Question, Badly Worded

Tags: discussion

I have seen this question basically asked twice.  Both time are badly worded but the question itself is a good one.

https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/6670/which-parts-of-the-body-will-produce-a-knockout-when-hit-in-a-certain-way

Should we make a new question to answer this in an MMA context?  Plenty of stats available for that and the question is fair.

We could also perhaps open as second question to focus on techniques for self defence. (which I imagine would be similar to the answer in MMA but with neck strikes added (with perhaps a mention of kick to knee and strike to eye as alternatives to a knockout).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general it is a very good question, but IMVHO not one suitable for asking on this site because:

- it is asking for an extended list of techniques/locations
- it will provoke argument when someone disagrees with any particular entry
- many of the techniques require training, knowledge and skill to be able to apply correctly
- personally I would be reluctant to just start publishing a list - it's the holy grail for any martial arts wannabe

The example you linked to was a bad question no matter how you judge it. It was vague and open ended, had zero research behind it, and I would suggest the OP has little training (if any).

Note that I'm not against questions asking about knockouts, I just don't think this site is always the right place for it. Even simple questions like:

> There's a great knockout spot on the side of the jaw, how do I attack it?

is verging on not suitable for here. It is very specific with its location, but there can be a hundred different established ways to attack that spot depending on which art you want to talk about - which is where it starts to become unsuitable for this site because it requires an extremely extended discussion or answer(s).

### So how can we cover this sort of topic?

Some of this stuff can be covered in the tag wikis. Some of it can be in a question if it is specific enough. Questions that have several possible answers are still fine even though only one can be marked. But what we must avoid is:

- lots of discussion instead of answers
- questions that ask for lengthy and non-definitive lists
- questions that produce one line answers (or lists of one liners) - we want explanations and detail
- answers that are highly debatable and likely divide the community along cultural or martial art lines

### But wait, there's more...

So that's my response, both personally and as a moderator, based on my many years experience using the Stack Exchange network. But frequently boundaries are vague and none of this is set in stone - **the site belongs to the community** and it is up to the community to set the direction. What are your thoughts on this? Does someone think they know a way that this can work and they want to take a crack at it?

Comment: All Good points. A Tag Wiki sounds great.  How do we make one for knockouts?

Comment: I've created the tag [tag:knockout] (you had enough rep to do this, but I did it anyway). So if you [go to this link](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knockout) you will be able to start editing the wiki associated with it. Your edit may still need to be approved (tag wiki editing isn't mentioned in the [rep list](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)), but that should be a mere formality.

Comment: @HuwEvans Anyone with 150 rep can create tags. I'm not exactly sure when you can edit tag descriptions, but I think it's a similarly low barrier. You just create a new tag when adding tags to a question, then edit the tag description, which submits it for approval.

Comment: I wrote up a brief explanation.  Would it be appropriate to provide references here?

Comment: @HuwEvans Absolutely, go for it. Lists of references in the tag wikis are good. For example, check [this wiki for the C++ language](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: OK. Ive added a few easy ones. Ill continue later.

Comment: I think we can have "What are my best options to produce knockout using XYZ methods under ABC rules/conditions?"  "using Karate in full contact competition", "using a baton in self defense" etc. that would narrow down the answers to something more reasonable. (also if you don't know enough to be able to define your methods and the conditions, you're probably not informed enough to make use of the answers anyway).